# Apex InvocableMethod not showing up in Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, apexactionfunction

The Apex class is not in a package, has global visibility, is Active, has passing tests with 86% coverage, and the method has the `@InvocableMethod` tag but it is still not showing up in the picklist when trying to add an Apex Action to a flow.

I'm wondering if there's anything I'm missing.

Comment: I am seeing a delay to populate the picklist when I did it yesterday....I am not sure if it is your case....

Comment: That could be it, how long was your delay?

Comment: I believe I was not clear. When I click in the picklist to choice the class (process builder screen), looks like that the picklist is populated in this moment...So, there is a very small delay.

Comment: Are you on Summer 19? also can you try compile all  classes and try again?

Comment: I have the same issue. I type the first letter from my class and it come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still experiencing this issue try updating your class metadata **apiVersion to 48**. I had the same problem and tried everything else. When I updated the apiVersion, it works immediately.

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely a bug in the new flow designer. It's not because of Sum19 release. I also faced a similar issue recently in Spring 19 scratch org and when switched back to legacy flow builder, I was able to add invocable action in flow. This link also reports the same issue. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000E47kQAC
I wasn't able to find a bug reported on success community.

Comment: That's disappointing to hear :( thanks for the info

Comment: Yeah. I am hoping that it gets fixed ASAP because my current work is heavyily dependent on flows and invocable actions.

Comment: I ran all the unit tests and then is appeared for me.

Answer (score 0):

**I had had the same issue but after adding label and description of @InvocableMethod. That was strange...it works to me.**

```
public class Abc {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Method Label' description='Method description')
    public static <YourReturnType> invokeMethod(params here) {

      //put your code here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the list of things you can try:

- change parameter type
- recompile all classes
- run tests
- add label and description to invocable attribute

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and the issue was the class had become invalid due to a dependent class being refactored.

Try save the class, and resolve an errors that may occur.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code from current class and create a new class with some different name. And then try to search the new name in Flow. Most of the time this trick works. Please try and check.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

To get rid of this, go to **setup** -> **session settings** -> uncheck "**Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance**" box under caching.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. At first glance, I don't really see how this would be a browser caching issue. Can you go into more detail about how this is supposed to resolve the issue that the question is asking about?